# How can I do a join with JPA spring boot

Tags: sql, spring, jpa

This is the main entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "system_configuration")
public class SystemConfigurationDTO {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "systemConfigurationDTO")
    private List<SysConfigMetaDataDTO> sysConfigMetaDataDTO;
}
```

This is the table I want to join to SystemConfigurationDTO.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "system_configuration_metadata")
public class SysConfigMetaDataDTO {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "system_configuration_id")
    private Long systemConfigurationId;
}
```

The issue is that for each record pulled from system_configuration that id is queried against system_configuration_metadata. How do a join and pull data from both tables? I dont wanna do JPQL. I am using specification class to build WHERE clause. But im not sure how to select from both using join.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a join table so that the provider will do the join for you. Create a join table CONFIG_META with two fields, SYS_CONFIG_ID and SYS_CONFIG_META_ID. Then annotate the private reference fields like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "system_configuration")
public class SystemConfigurationDTO {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(
    name="CONFIG_META",
    joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="SYS_CONFIG_ID", referencedColumnName="ID" },
    inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="SYS_CONFIG_META_ID", referencedColumnName="ID") }        
   )
   private List<SysConfigMetaDataDTO> sysConfigMetaDataDTO;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "system_configuration_metadata")
public class SysConfigMetaDataDTO {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "system_configuration_id")
    private Long systemConfigurationId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sysConfigMetaDataDTO")
    private SystemConfigurationDTO sysConfigDTO;
}
```